# What makes a stack True?

Tags: python, data-structures

Basically, as the title entails - what makes a stack true?

```
1. stack = []
2. print(not stack)
True
3. stack.append(1)
4. print(not stack)
False
5. stack.append(2)
6. stack.append(3)
7. print(not stack)
False
```

Continue adding elements...

From the code, I realized that an empty stack will return True and a stack with elements will return False. Is that true? If not, please explain how stacks are true or false, also, will that logic follow queues, dictionaries, sets ....?

Comment: list's `__bool__` is truthy if it has nonzero length

Comment: @AnthonySottile "truthy"? Is it always true if it has a nonzero length? If not, what parameters will result in a nonzero length list to be false?

Comment: To comment on @AnthonySottile Read about python magic methods that are prefixed and suffixed with two underscore characters.

Comment: @Chintan - nothing -- `bool()` of a nonzero length list is _always_ `True`.

Comment: If you have one or more item in the list, the length will be greater than zero and the list will evaluate to True. For the others, read the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are elements inside the stack, it will return `True` when asked if it is True or not.

On the examples you gave you're asking the opposite,

```
not stack
```

which will return `True` whenever the stack does not have any element, and `False` when it has elements inside.

Comment: this isn't exactly cprrect, "any other datastructure" can choose to override `__bool__` in any way it seems fit

Answer (score 2):

Its a `list`, not a "stack" and its truth value is covered in the python language specification [Boolean operations](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations), which also covers truthiness for other basic types.

> In the context of Boolean operations, and also when expressions are
> used by control flow statements, the following values are interpreted
> as false: False, None, numeric zero of all types, and empty strings
> and containers (including strings, tuples, lists, dictionaries, sets
> and frozensets). All other values are interpreted as true.
> User-defined objects can customize their truth value by providing a
> **bool**() method.

So, empty lists are `False`, non empty lists are `True`. This also holds for dictionaries, etc., but user defined containers can decide for themselves. A pandas dataframe, for instance, gets mad if you even ask:

```
>>> df=pd.DataFrame([0,1,0])
>>> bool(df)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/td/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 1479, in __nonzero__
    f"The truth value of a {type(self).__name__} is ambiguous. "
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```